# The use of "within"

Tags: prepositions

I am still confused with prepositions.

> I think I can't bear the situation within the next 30 days

Is that sentence correct?

Or there are other prepositions that might suit the sentence, replacing 'within'?

Comment: **within** is NOT idiomatic. **For** would fit.

Comment: We speak of some event happening _within the next 30 days_, meaning 'at some time during that period', but we don't use _within_ for an ongoing 'situation'.